# Using Multi-Output Device Freezes My Computer

Tags: audio

I've been trying to figure out a way to capture my Mac's desktop audio to stream it with OBS. Every tutorial tells me to use Soundflower, iShowu, Screenflick Loopback, etc, and route it through Audio MIDI Setup as a Multi-Output Device. I've tried all of the different drivers.

[image]

The problem here is whenever I enable "Multi-Output Device" as my output in the System Preferences > Sound control panel, the audio gets completely muted, and the Audio MIDI Setup application and the Sound System Preferences panel stop responding. I have to wait around 2-3 minutes to switch back to the Built-in Output. This renders Multi-Output Device useless on my computer when I have two outputs setup through the Audio MIDI Setup.

Is this a Catalina problem? There seems to be no other threads I can find with similar problems.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Does the problem also occur with two *hardware* devices selected for the multi-output device (e.g. headphones and speakers?)

Comment: I'd uninstall all the others & just set up Loopback. You've got multiple things all thinking they're in charge of routing the same audio, all falling over each other.